# Web cam not working on ThinkPad P14s AMD Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, webcam

The integrated web cam on the ThinkPad P14S AMD is not working while running on Ubuntu 20.04

I run lsusb and I get the following

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6d0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I run uname -r

```
5.11.0-27-generic
```

I run but nothing happens

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

When I attempt to run cheese - this is what I see [black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUNkA.png)

I did find this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757 but not much of an update February

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install v4l-utils with

```
$ sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

After that try:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

You should see the list of all video device, and should be something like

```
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
```

Then try cheese with some of the video device you've got. For example cheese -d /dev/video0 and cheese -d /dev/video1 and so on.